# Define Parameters within Complex Polygon tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, polygon

Fairly new to python, brand new to tkinter. My objective is to randomly generate trees on a landmass, however, the landmass is a complex polygon, so simply restricting my randint values to a rectangle doesn't exactly do it. I was hoping for something like 'get_pixel' to verify a point is the colour of the landmass before adding the coordinates to the list, or even selecting coordinates from a list of coordinates within the polygon, but tkinter doesn't work like that. find_overlapping/find_enclosed also seem to be for box shaped problems.

In short: Is there a way to define coordinate limits based on a complex polygon?

EDIT: It’s for a class, tkinter is required, end result is a static scene drawn in a canvas. Just wanted to randomize trees without having them in the river. I’ll post some code when I get home tonight.

Comment: I know tkinter claims to have a "high speed' canvas, but in reality it is painfully slow. I don't know how complex your "complex polygon" is, but tkinter might be the wrong road to go down, altogether. Maybe PyGame or matplotlib is more suited to your needs.

Comment: See [how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/).

Comment: Have you written any possible code as for us to know what exactly you are drawing the polygon on, are you drawing the polygon on a tkinter canvas or just a tkinter window?

Comment: I suggest providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also as @MichaelGuidry pointed out, from what I can assume you are trying to make somewhat of a game or simulation for which using pygame is a much better choice.

Comment: In specific I would suggest you to check out [pygame's draw module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) and also the [pygame's gfxdraw module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html) which is a more advanced drawing interface. They have pixel methods too.

Comment: So you can draw each pixel and store its info like x, y, color etc. in a list as a sublist, then you can at any time you can alter that info list, and since the screen will be drawn every frame your change will automatically be visible and to get info of a pixel you would just need it's index to query about it from the info list[FOR PYGAME.]